# Convert black to white in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, black, white

I am having a hard time replicating the second image style in the first.  The football field image needs the black to be gone and be replaced throughout the image with a white color.  What is the best way to do this in Photoshop and get the same result as the second image?

**Image To Convert**

[image]

**Replicate Style**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to invert the colors (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>), then add a new layer of pure white (or the gradient @JohnnyKutnowski suggested).  Reduce the white layer's opacity slightly to let the image show through.  I set my white layer's opacity to 88% and this is the result:

[image: Image inverted with nearly opaque white layer]

Comment: This seems reasonable. I might suggest adding a motion blur. Maybe duplicate the layer -> motion blur at the desired angle -> lower opacity of the blurred layer

Comment: Let me try this out, looks exactly like what I need.

Answer (score 3):

I think your approach isn't the right one in this case.

To achieve what you see in the second image, I would go for a gradient map on the original image with a gray to white gradient. I'm sure that's exactly how they got to that result.

It's easy to do, just add a **Gradient Map Adjustment Layer**, and choose the colours in the gradient selector.

That being said, to select a colour and than change it, I usually go with `Select > Color Range...` and adjust the fuzziness to my needs. But this is what I call a *dirty* method, just like the Magic Wand.